# What does it mean that sub sigma-algebra is independent of a random value

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Let $F$ be a $σ$-algebra, $G$ is sub $σ$-algebra of $F$, $X$ is RV.

I found such definition
$$"X \ \text{ is independent  of   } G"$$

is equivalent to $$"\forall A\in G,  X  \text{ is  independent  of } _".$$

I was wondering why it is enough to take only the indicator function?

Comment: Can you share your source, please?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is independent of $I_A$ for each $A \in G$ then $P(X^{-1}(E)\cap A )=P(X^{-1}(E)\cap  I_A^{-1}(\{1\}))= P(X^{-1}(E)) P(A)$ for any Borel set $E$ in the real line and any $A \in G$. This also implies that if $Y$ is any random variable measurable w.r.t. $G$ then $X$ and $Y$ are independent: $P(X^{-1}(E)\cap Y^{-1}(F))=(X^{-1}(E))P(Y^{-1}(F))$ because $Y^{-1}(F) \in G$ for any Borel set $F$.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I still have a question. Where does the equality (−1()∩−1({1}))=(−1())() come from?

Comment: @SamMarcuvan Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, so I am duplicating. Where does the equality $(^{−1}()∩^{−1}_(\{1\}))=(^{−1}())()$ come from?

Comment: @SamMarcuvan By definition of independence and the fact that $I_A^{-1}(\{1\}$ is exactly $A$.